# undefined reference when using SFML

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, linker, sfml

I am trying to compile a program using the SFML library

My source looks like this:

```
//main.cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main(){
    sf::Color c;
}
```

I am compiling like this
`g++ -IC:/dev/include -c main.cpp`
and linking like this
`g++ -LC:/dev/lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network main.o -o main.exe`

I am getting this error when linking:
`main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to '__imp__ZN2sf5ColorC1Ev'`

What am I doing wrong?
I compiled the SFML binaries myself using gcc 6.1 and cmake

Comment: Why don't you use the pre-made SFML libraries?

Comment: I tried, but it gave me the same error. Then I build it from source in hopes of fixing it

Comment: A few things to check - in the properties, make sure you are using Active(Win32), your folder: [Game name] -> [Game name] contains all the .dll files

Comment: The properties of what?

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: Nope, I am not.

Comment: Can't help, sorry. When I first used SFML, I had similar problems. I was using 32-bit with 64-bit settings

Comment: See answer by @VTT. That solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your command like this, specifying libraries *after* input:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.o -LC:/dev/lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network
```

The order of linking parameters is important because linker will proceed inputs sequentially. For each item it will fill existing list of undefined symbols with symbols exported from the current item, and then populate that list with symbols not defined in current item. So when `main.o` is last list of undefined symbols contains everything required by `main.o`, but there is no more items (libraries) to fill those missing symbols. Note that this implies that the order of libraries is important as well so more "generic" libraries should be kept closer to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Can you tell me why that is?

Comment: @KnutZuidema The order of linking parameters is important because it will proceed inputs sequentially. For each item it will fill existing list of undefined symbols with symbols exported from the current item, and then populate that list with symbols not defined in current item. So when `main.o` is last list of undefined symbols contains everything required by `main.o` but there is no more items (libraries) to fill those gaps. Note that this implies that the order of libraries is important as well so more "generic" libraries should be kept closer to the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.